# Views: how to enable Title Link per role?

Tags: views, entities, navigation, users

In Drupal 7 Views, there is an option to Link title field to the original piece of content. How can I enable the link per role? I only want to show the link for administrator and staff, so it will be much easier to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 6 had a view node permission, but it was removed from Drupal 7 for some reason.
This module adds it to Drupal 7:
https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions

If only the administrator and staff have the view node permission, only they should see the link in your view.

This of course will also only allow administrators and staff to view the node page too.

You could also create a template for that view field.
In the view settings, under advanced, there should be a 'theme' link. Click it to see what your field theme file should be named.